# Figure label separator in Elsevier double column class cas-dc

Tags: pdftex, elsarticle, els-cas

I am preparing a manuscript using Elsevier `cas-dc` double column class and facing difficulty to change the label separator for figures. The default is a colon so that a figure label is formatted as Fig. 1: However, I would like to change this to Fig. 1. instead. I have tried using

```
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period]{caption}
```

without success. The figure label is still Fig. 1: With so many fixes to apply to this cas-dc, I am quite frustrated. In the following, I am giving the MWE that I am using and would appreciate any help on this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[caption=false, font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{multirow}

% Without the following, cas-dc does not center captions
\makeatletter
\def\redefparbox{\def\@parboxrestore{\@arrayparboxrestore\let\\\@normalcr
  \if@minipage\expandafter\@gobbletwo\fi
  \@firstofone{\centering\casscparboxtest}}}
\def\casscparboxtest#1{%
  \ifx\rightskip#1\relax\expandafter\dimen@\else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi\@gobble{#1}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period]{caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period}

% Rename figure label to Fig. instead of Figure:
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{Fig. \thefigure}
\makeatother

% Remove ORCID footnote
\let\printorcid\relax 

% Fix cas-dc textwidth so that captions for two-column floats are placed correctly
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\FullWidth}{\textwidth}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[align=\redefparbox]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.95]{Figure1.pdf}

    \caption{Caption for figure.}
    \label{Figlabel}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`els-cas` has the `:` hardcoded in the definition of `\__make_fig_caption:nn` (you can change that if you want).  A sneakier way is:

```latex
% Rename figure label to Fig <num>. instead of Figure <num>:
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{Fig. \thefigure.\@gobble}
\makeatother
```

The definition of `\fnum@figure` writes `Fig. <num>.` and then ends with `\@gobble`, which consumes the next token, which is, in this case, the `:`.

Comment: This really helped.